# Posicionar imagen y textos dentro de un div

Tags: bootstrap-4

Quiero hacer que una imagen me quede a la derecha de un texto que estoy agregando. Esta es mas o menos la estructura que tengo ahora:

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center border-bottom border-dark" style="height:50%;">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis tortor, egestas quis congue eget, semper in ante. Ut faucibus augue nulla, eget feugiat mi lacinia nec.
            Fusce non sapien non ex faucibus ultrices eget ut erat. Maecenas bibendum posuere felis vel porttitor. Donec non massa quis nunc tempus suscipit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-center" style="height:50%;')">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
            <p class="lead">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis tortor, egestas quis congue eget, semper in ante. Ut faucibus augue nulla, eget feugiat mi lacinia nec.
                Fusce non sapien non ex faucibus ultrices eget ut erat. Maecenas bibendum posuere felis vel porttitor. Donec non massa quis nunc tempus suscipit.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero, es que dentro de cada row, ademas de tener un h2 y un p, tener una imagen y hacer que este a la izquierda o derecha de estos.

¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Tienes una idea sobre qué tamaño tiene que ser tu imagen respecto del texto que tienes al lado? (50-50, 75-25, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero utilizar los elementos media de bootstrap, los cuales tienen multiples configuraciones y orden, [aquí la referencia](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/media-object/).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row align-items-center" style="height:50%;')">
  <div class="media">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/MiG-29K_at_MAKS-2007_airshow_%28altered%29.jpg" class="mr-3" alt="..." width="300">
    <div class="media-body">
      <h2 class="mt-0 text-center">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p class="lead">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam turpis tortor, egestas quis congue eget, semper in ante. Ut faucibus augue nulla, eget feugiat mi lacinia nec.
            Fusce non sapien non ex faucibus ultrices eget ut erat. Maecenas bibendum posuere felis vel porttitor. Donec non massa quis nunc tempus suscipit.
        </p>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, gracias por pasarme el dato de la clase media, no la conocia todavia.

Comment: Me alegra mucho haber sido de ayuda, recuerda marcar la respuesta como la aceptada si fue la más precisa.

Answer (score -1):

De la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row align-items-center border-bottom border-dark"
    style="height: 50%;">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="row">               
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2><p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p></div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="">
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-center" style="height: 50%;">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="row">               
            <div class="col">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2><p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p></div>
            <div class="col">
                <img src="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, termine usando la clase media ya que me resulta mas facil hacer todo con bootstrap! Pero gracias igual!